# Is Cloud storage used to store messages in Cloud Pub/Sub?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

We are evaluating Cloud Pub/Sub for our queue requirements and want to understand if message is persisted in queue and in cloud storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Pub/Sub uses its own underlying storage system to store messages and does not store them in Cloud Storage. There is no way to access the underlying files in which messages are stored. If you do want messages sent via Google Cloud Pub/Sub to be stored in Google Cloud Storage as well, you will need to set up a subscriber whose job it is to write the data to files. As an example, there is a [Cloud Dataflow template designed to do this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubtogcstext).

Comment: Then is there a default encryption that Google would use for these messages in its storage?

Comment: Messages are encrypted when stored by default, yes. Cloud Pub/Sub also supports [customer-managed encryption keys](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/cmek).

Answer (score 1):

It's important to not mix the two product.

[PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) is a global message queuing platform. Thus, you can post message in it

[Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/) is a blob storage, you can store file in it. Be careful, it's not a filesystem, you can't update the blob, optionally replaces version if you activate the versioning.

What you can do, is to [create a notification when event occur on a bucket to post a message in PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes). The message content the blob URI that trigger the event and thereby, you can process it.

*You are charge on the message size in PubSub, don't push the blob content in it, it's not the right place!*